# Can a scorm lesson (made Captivate HTML5) be played in a browser page?

Tags: html, api, browser, scorm

When I click on the index file of a SCORM package I receive a "Unable to acquire LMS,API content may not playback properly and results may not be recorded" within the browser page.  However once past the error message the file plays back perfectly stopping where required, as well as totaling the Q & A session.  No matter what browser I open this in I receive the same message. I have JavaScript installed. I edited the index file to read <0 from <9 as suggested on one site.

```
if(document.documentMode < 0)
        {
            document.body.innerHTML = "";
```

Am I attempting the impossible? Does the package need to be hosted within a LMS such as moodle? My purpose is simply a standalone lesson without the additional information supplied by an LMS.

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, yes. A SCO in a SCORM package will attempt to initialize itself via a call to the LMS' API letting it know that it has initialized. To do so the first thing that package will do is look for the JavaScript based API that is the LMS' implementation of the SCORM RTE (Run Time Environment). So the message you are getting above is because the SCO is unable to locate the SCORM RTE API (because it isn't implemented by your page). Whether the rest of the content will "play" is very content specific, some will, some likely won't. Most SCORM content will have additional calls to the SCORM RTE to do things like capture completion, success (pass/fail), a score, etc. Some content may work in a "standalone" fashion where the calls that it would make to the LMS' SCORM implementation are turned into no-ops, but a learner would not receive credit for having consumed the content.

https://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/ is a good resource for more about how SCORM content functions.